# How To Connect to remote SQL Database in Titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile

I have some problem in connecting to remote database from Titanium.

I found some of the answer we can use

The usual way would be to create a web service for the server, and allow it to negotiate the interaction between client and server, passing data back and forth using JSON.

But i don have any idea about JSON

I tried searching on the web but of no help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium can understand only the client side. Whereas the database would exist on the server side. Therefore the only way to read database is to have a backend script (web service) which would read the database and forward the details to the front end in form of JSON or XML.

JSON is very easy to understand and learn. You can checkout www.json.org.